# Using more memory than available

Tags: python, windows, memory, memory-management

I have written a program that expands a database of prime numbers. This program is written in python and runs on windows 10 (x64) with 8GB RAM.

The program stores all primes it has found in a `list` of `integers` for further calculations and uses approximately `6-7GB` of RAM while running. During some runs however, this figure has dropped to below `100MB`. The memory usage then stays low for the duration of the run, though increasing as expected as more numbers are added to the prime array. Note that not all runs result in a memory drop.

*Memory usage measured with task manager*

These, seemingly random, drops has led me the following theories:

1. There's a bug in my code, making it drop critical data and messing up the results (most likely but not supported by the results)
2. Python just happens to optimize my code extremely well after a while.
3. Python or Windows is compensating for my over-usage of the RAM by cleaning out portions of my prime-number array that aren't used that much. (eventually resulting in incorrect calculations)
4. Python or Windows is compensating for my over-usage of the RAM by allocating disk space instead of ram.

## Questions

1. What could be the reason(s) for this memory drop?
2. How does python handle programs that use more than available RAM?
3. How does Windows handle programs that use more than available RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1, 2, and 3 are incorrect theories.

4 is correct. Windows (not Python) is moving some of your process memory to swap space. This is almost totally transparent to your application - you don't need to do anything special to respond to or handle this situation. The only thing you will notice is your application may get slower as information is written to and read from disk. But it all happens transparently. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory for more information.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming then that what's left in the RAM is the data most used (meaning the first part of the list, being iterated almost all the time) as well as the most newly added data (the last part of the list)? Whereas the most unsued data (the middle) is sent to the swap space?

Comment: @FelixZY: Maybe. Windows (which is managing the virtual memory) has no knowledge of which part of the list is which. It's just pages of memory, some of which seem to be used more often than others. The OS swaps out those that don't seem to be used much, and as an application writer you don't have much control or knowledge about which is which.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of paging? Windows dumps some ram (that hasn't been used in a while) to your hard drive to keep your computer from running out or ram and ultimately crashing.

Only Windows deals with memory management. Although, if you use Windows 10, it will also compress your memory, somewhat like a zip file.

Comment: I have heard of paging but I wasn't sure it could be applied in this way. See theory #4 in my question.

Comment: Yeah Python apps don't do it any different than any other app.